# UICollectionViewCells not appearing after reloadData call from notification when initially empty

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have an iOS messaging app, that displays the home screen as soon as the app is loaded upon initial launch.

If a user decided to go straight to the messages screen then it will be initially blank whilst the messages are fetched from our server.

I post a notification from my messages model, every time I add a new message in order to reload my MessagesCollectionView:

```
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .reloadMessagesCollectionView, object: nil)
```

I then have an observer that I add to receive this notification in my MessagesViewController

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(reloadMessagesCollectionView(_:)), name: .reloadMessagesCollectionView, object: nil)
    }
```

When a notification is received, this function is called:

```
    func reloadMessagesCollectionView(_ notification: Notification) {

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.messagesCollectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

However, despite the messageModel being populated, the reloadData being called and print statements showing that the collectionView datasource methods are receiving the correct data, the collectionView stays blank and does not display the newly populated cells.

Going to the home screen and then back again results in the MessagesCollectionView being correctly populated.

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong or need to add?